# Convertendo de HTML/CSS para pdf usando pandoc no R

Tags: html, r, pdf, rmarkdown

Pessoal estou tendo problemas para converter meu arquivo html/css gerado no RMarkdown.

Vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Segue meu codigo:

Meu arquivo .Rmd

````
---
title: "Table"
output:
  html_document:
    css: "test.css"
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
data(iris)
kable(iris)
```
````

Meu arquivo .css:

```
.main-container { 
     max-width: 1600px !important;
 } 
    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
    th {
        background-color: #FF6319;
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    tbody {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    hr {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

Quando eu rodo o comando: `rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("C:/Users/user/Downloads/myfile.html", output = "meuarquivo.pdf")`

O pdf é gerado mas não com a customização em .css

Tambem tentei utilizar o google chrome pra isso  e nada.

O que peciso fazer para corrigir isso?

Muito obrigada pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De maneira geral Pandoc vai usar `LateX` para converter à pdf. Uma opção é configurar o estilo em linguagem `LateX`.

Para que Pandoc possa interpretar `css` como estilo, você vai precisar instalar [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html):

```
pandoc -t html5 --css test.css test.html -o output.pdf
```